# What is the prefered REST url pattern of requesting a object that is part of a collection?

Tags: rest, backbone.js

We have REST API with a collection of channels. When requesting a channel, should I use the channels collection endpoint or channel object endpoint?

```
/channels/{id}/     // this?
/channel/{id}/      // or this?
```

I want this to work as seamless with backbone.js as possible when it comes to backbone model URL attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/` on the end should not make a difference for preference (too confusing for users if it does!) and while you can use singular or plural as you choose, be consistent throughout your app *and make the individuals children of the collection*. Think of the collection as being like a directory of individuals.

Answer (score 3):

Most books about restful API's suggest that you use the singular for your endpoint. You get the collection from there as well as operations on single instances of the collection.

Calling:

```
 GET /channel -> List of channels
 GET /channel/{id} -> Gets a channel
 POST /channel -> Creates a new channel
 PUT /channel/{id} -> Updates an existing channel
```

and so on. Nevertheless for Backbone this makes no difference as you can customize the URL behavior as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

At some point its really just preference. Some people argue the definition of REST apis should always be plural. Mainly I always get annoyed with `/channel` being a list, so I naturally gravitate to treating everything in the plural `/channels`. Which is backwards from what they tell you to do in table design: treat everything as a singular. At the end of the day, just being consistent will make many people that use your apis happy.